# Sum of Rotated Integral Image (RSAT) not return sum of original pixel value

Tags: image, matlab, integral

I have an image, eg, matrix A;

A= [156 159 158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;

160 154 157 158 157 159 158 158 158 160;

156 159 158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;

160 154 157 158 157 **159** 158 158 158 160;

156 153 155 159 **159   155 156**   155 155 157;

155 155 155 **157   156 159 152 158**   156 158;

156 153 157 156 **153   155 154**   155 157 156;

159 159 156 158 156 **159** 157 161 162 157;

158 155 158 154 156 160 162 155 159 161;

155 154 157 158 160 160 159 160 158 161]

To get pixel value for RSAT(x,y),
RSAT(x,y) =  RSAT(x-1,y-1) + RSAT(x-1,y+1) - RSAT(x-2,y) + I(x-1,y)+ I(x,y); where I is original image(matrixA).

Matrix B (after calculated RSAT):

[0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;

0   156 159 158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;

156 475 627 629 629 626 632 631 632 631 475;

475 943 1258    1413    1413    **1418**    1416    1422    1420    1265    949;

943 1574    2042    2357    **2515  2518    2523**  2522    2371    2053    1583;

1574    2358    2980    **3456  3779    3936    3938    3786**  3468    3002    2370;

2358    3291    4080    4712    **5193  5514    5513**  5192    4730    4096    3317;

3291    4391    5331    6129    6760    **7079**    7082    6763    6133    5358    4410;

4391    5646    6752    7692    8329    8637    8643    8334    7707    6766    5671;

5646    7069    8321    9266    9881    10205   10208   9906    9283    8341    7084;

7069    8634    9892    10825   11454   11768   11788   11478   10855   9918    8663]

Total sum of Region (bold region) at matrix A  = 2041 .
However, sum of Region (bold region ) at matrix B= 1880. As a integral image theory, it suppose return same value as matrix A, 2041.

Here my code (matlab)

Kindly please assist me. 
Thank you.

```
I= [156 159 158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;
160 154 157 158 157 159 158 158 158 160;
156 159 158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;
160 154 157 158 157 159 158 158 158 160;
156 153 155 159 159 155 156 155 155 157;
155 155 155 157 156 159 152 158 156 158;
156 153 157 156 153 155 154 155 157 156;
159 159 156 158 156 159 157 161 162 157;
158 155 158 154 156 160 162 155 159 161;
155 154 157 158 160 160 159 160 158 161];

Dummy_Ori_Img =padarray(I,[1 1],'pre') ;
Dummy_Ori_Img2 =padarray(Dummy_Ori_Img,[0 1],'replicate','post') ;

%calculate RSAT
RSAT = zeros(size(Dummy_Ori_Img2));
[Height_Dummy,Width_Dummy]=size (Dummy_Ori_Img2);
for x =1:Height_Dummy
for  y = 1:Width_Dummy
    if x-2<=0 || (x-2)>Height_Dummy || y>=Width_Dummy ||y==1
        RSAT1=0;
    else
        RSAT1= RSAT(x-2,y);
    end
    if x-1<=0 || y-1<=0 || (x-1)>Height_Dummy || (y-1)>Width_Dummy
        RSAT2=0;
    else
        RSAT2=RSAT(x-1,y-1);
    end
    if x-1<=0 ||  (x-1)>Height_Dummy || (y+1)>Width_Dummy 
        RSAT3=0;
    else
        RSAT3=RSAT(x-1,y+1);
    end 
    if x-1<=0 || y<=0 || x>Width_Dummy || y>Height_Dummy
        DOI1=0;
    else
        DOI1=Dummy_Ori_Img(x-1,y);
    end
    if x<=0 || y<=0 || x>Width_Dummy || y>Height_Dummy
        DOI2=0;
    else
        DOI2=Dummy_Ori_Img(x,y);
    end
    RSAT(x,y)= RSAT3 + RSAT2-RSAT1 + DOI2 + DOI1;
end
end
RSATnew  = RSAT (1:size(Dummy_Ori_Img,1),1: size(Dummy_Ori_Img,2)  );
outer_upright_kernel = ones (3,3);
TiltedKernel=ceil(imrotate(outer_upright_kernel,45,'bilinear','loose'));
[Height_tilt,Width_tilt]=size (TiltedKernel);
HalfTilt_x= floor(Width_tilt/2);
HalfTilt_y= floor(Height_tilt/2);
% calculate sum of region
xi=6;
yi=6;
fourpoints = [xi yi HalfTilt_x HalfTilt_y];
row_val=fourpoints(1,1);
col_val=fourpoints(1,2);
img_width=fourpoints(1,3);
img_length=fourpoints(1,4);
if row_val-1<=0 ||col_val-img_width<=0
    T1to = 0;
else
    T1to = RSATnew(row_val-1,col_val-img_width);
    TiltOuter1 = [row_val-1,col_val-img_width];
end
if row_val-1-img_length<=0 || col_val-1<=0
    T2to =  0;
else
    T2to = RSATnew(row_val-1-img_length,col_val);
    TiltOuter2 = [row_val-1-img_length,col_val];
end
if row_val + img_length<=0 ||col_val<=1
    T3to = 0;
else
    T3to = RSATnew(row_val + img_length,col_val);
    TiltOuter3 = [row_val + img_length,col_val];
end
if col_val+img_width+1 <=0
    T4to = 0;
else
    T4to = RSATnew(row_val,col_val+img_width+1);
    TiltOuter4 = [row_val,col_val+img_width+1];
end
TiltOuterSum = T2to + T3to - T1to - T4to;
```

Comment: show us your code or calculation

Comment: nio, i adding my code & change example.Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Lienhart(2002) (http://www.multimedia-computing.de/mediawiki/images/5/52/MRL-TR-May02-revised-Dec02.pdf),

the RSAT (x,y)= RSAT(x-1,y-1) + RSAT(x+1,y-1) - RSAT(x,y-2) + I(x,y) + I(x,y-1)

For your matrix, A

> [156 159  158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;
>
> 160   154 157 158 157 159 158 158 158 160;
>
> 156   159 158 155 158 **156** 159 158 157 158;
>
> 160   154 157 158 **157   159 158**   158 158 160;
>
> 156   153 155 **159   159 155 156 155**   155 157;
>
> 155   155 155 **157   156 159 152 158**   156 158;
>
> 156   153 157 156 **153   155 154**   155 157 156;
>
> 159   159 156 158 156 **159** 157 161 162 157;
>
> 158   155 158 154 156 160 162 155 159 161;
>
> 155   154 157 158 160 160 159 160 158 161].

Then, RSAT of matrix A should be:

> [156  159 158 155 158 156 159 158 157 158;
>
> 475   627   629     629     626    #***632***#      631     632     631    475;
>
> 787   1258    1413    1413    1418    **1416**    1422    1420    1265    791;
>
> 1099  1886    2357    2515    **2518  2523    2522**  2371    1895    1108;
>
> 1415  2505    #***3300***#    **3779  3936    3938    3786    3310**  #***2527***#    1421;
>
> 1717  3137    4237    **5037  5514    5513    5034    4255**  3147    1734;
>
> 2033  3757    5186    6285    **6923  6924    6288**  5184    3775    2040;
>
> 2355  4394    6118    7386    8004    #***8012***#    7385    6124    4396    2354;
>
> 2678  5030    6908    8149    8787    8784    8167    6913    5024    2674;
>
> 2988  5501    7376    8621    9245    9262    8633    7382    5508    2992]

Total sum of region (bold region in matrix A - I have altered based on the paper) is **2817**. Based on RSAT, should be calculated as `8012 + 632 - 3300 - 2527 = 2817`.

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please *explain* what the solution you're showing does, and *why/how* that code answers the question.